# Appended items not reacting to event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am adding some list items to a list on the go using jquery. There are two classes given to each list items. One controls CSS attributes and other controls the **click** on the list item. The list item looks something like this :

> < li class="il l3" >Gigabyte Wars< /li >

Here 'il' controls CSS and l3 controls the click function.

My problem is that when I add list items on the go, the regular click function defined for all list items does not work for the new ones. Any suggesstions ?

Comment: What does the jquery look like that you've tried?

Comment: **This is the holy grail answer:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector `$(".l3")` adds the event handler to existing elements in the DOM matching it. If you're adding new items, you can either specify the event handler on the document, as noted in [Justin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24493514/225386), or, if you need finer-grained control, you can dynamically add the event handler to new items:

```
$("<li>", { class: "l3" }).appendTo(someList).click(function () { ... });
```

Comment: I use this 


$('.orderedList').append('<li class="il l' + i + '">' + $('.nam').val() + '</li>').click(function()
{
        alert("Description : \n             "+$('.desc').val().trim()+"\n\nLocation : \n"+$('.loc').val().trim());
});

and it doesn't work !

Comment: You're assigning the click handler to the list (`$('.orderedList')`), not the underlying list items. Also, you're adding raw HTML that jQuery parses and appends. You might want to use the `appendTo` technique: `$("<li>", { class: "il l"+i }).text($('.nam').val()).appendTo($('.orderedList')).click(function () { ... })`

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using:

```
$('.l3').click(function(){});
```

Use (be more specific than `document` if you can:

```
$(document).on('click', '.l3', function(){});
```

The latter will create a delegated event handler which will handle events for any elements created in the future as well as the elements that already exist.